# Does DisplayMetrics.xdpi and DisplayMetrics.ydpi change depending on the screen orientation

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Following is what android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) say about `DisplayMetrics.xdpi` and `DisplayMetrics.ydpi`.

> **xdpi**
>
> The exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the X
>   dimension.
>
> **ydpi**
>
> The exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the Y
>   dimension.

It is not clear to me what is meant by X dimension and Y dimension. Usually, the X dimension is the horizontal dimension and the Y dimension is the vertical dimension, so `DisplayMetrics.xdpi` and `DisplayMetrics.ydpi` should change depending on the screen orientation.

But, when I tested with following code, it can be observed that these two parameters won't change with the screen orientation.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
Log.i("test", "xdpi: " + displayMetrics.xdpi + ", ydpi: " + displayMetrics.ydpi);
```

So, what is actually meant by X dimension and Y dimension? Should `DisplayMetrics.xdpi` and `DisplayMetrics.ydpi` stay the same when orientation changed, or is this some kind of an issue with my device?